# Unable to add Codeigniter where in clause and where clause in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and working on a project where I need to add search filters on a page. The way its been setup under applications/core there is a MY_Model.php file and here it the get_result function it.

```
function get_result() {
  $this->db->from($this->tableName . ' ' . $this->alias);
  $this->db->select($this->selectFields, FALSE);

  for($j=0;$j<count($this->arrJoins);$j++){
    $this->db->join($this->arrJoins[$j][0], $this->arrJoins[$j][1], $this->arrJoins[$j][2]);
  }

  $this->db->like($this->arrLike);
  $this->db->or_like($this->arrOrLike);
  if(isset($this->custLikeStr) && count($this->custLikeStr) > 0){
    $this->db->where($this->custLikeStr);
  }
  $this->db->where($this->arrWhere);
  $this->db->order_by($this->sortBy, $this->sortOrder);
  $query = $this->db->get()->result();
  //echo '<br>'.$this->db->last_query();
  return $query;
}
```

There is a get_where function to build all where clauses

```
function get_where() {
  foreach($this->arrWhereInputs as $arrWhereInput) {
    if(isset($this->$arrWhereInput) && $this->$arrWhereInput != ''){
      $this->arrWhere[$this->fieldAlias[$arrWhereInput].'.'.$arrWhereInput] = trim($this->$arrWhereInput);
    }
  }
  return $this->arrWhere;
}
```

And in the model file for the application so under application/models here is there is a select function we need to call to get results.

```
function select(){
    /* for search list */
    $this->arrLikeInputs = array('stock_title', 'stock_id', 'price_band', );
    $this->arrWhereInputs = array();
    $this->arrWhere = array();

    if ($this->input->post('record_per_page') != '') {
        $records_per_page = $this->input->post('record_per_page');
    } else {
        $records_per_page = ROWS_PER_PAGE;
    }

    if (!(isset($this->record_per_page) && $this->record_per_page != '')) {
        $this->record_per_page = ROWS_PER_PAGE;
    }

    $this->arrLike = $this->get_like();
    $this->arrWhere = $this->get_where();
    $this->arrWhere['SC.isDeleted'] = 0;

    /* for search list */
    if ($this->countQuery == 1) {
        $this->db->from($this->tableName . ' ' . $this->alias);
        $this->countSelectFields = 'COUNT(SC.stock_id) as cnt';
        $result['count'] = $this->get_count();
    }

    $result['resultarr'] = $this->get_result();
    $result['record_per_page'] = $records_per_page;

    return $result;
}
```

Now I want to add where in to my query and I have tried a few ways but it just does not work.

I am getting confused on to where I am going wrong on such a simple thing.

So I have added a get_wherein function.

```
function get_wherein() {
  foreach($this->arrWhereInInputs as $arrWhereInInput) {
      if(isset($this->$arrWhereInInput) && $this->$arrWhereInInput != ''){
        $this->arrWhereIn[$this->fieldAlias[$arrWhereInInput].'.'.$arrWhereInInput] = trim($this->$arrWhereInInput);
      }
    }
    return $this->arrWhereIn;
}
```

So I added `$this->arrWhereIn['Field'] = $arr` which does not work and also tried to to call `$this->db->where_in('field',$array)` in the select function directly that does not work either. In both the cases it gets ignored and the query is build without the "and where in".

Where am I going wrong and how to build this query?

Comment: It's called CodeIgniter. Secondly, I don't think your database model is set up  right if you need to write code this complicated to achieve simple filtering.

Comment: Yes CodeIgniter :) (fat fingers). I have just started working on application and never worked with this framework before. Can you please tell me what is missing?

Comment: I do not know how your databse tables look like, but I am pretty sure what you are trying to achieve can be simplified. Please provide your table structure or what your sql statement should look like in the end